# How to save RSS-feed to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, rss

Newbie here!

I'm working with trying to get data from diffrent RSS-feeds and save them to my MS SQL 2008 database. As of now I can successfully retrieve the data I want, see: [Paging of RSS using System.ServiceModel.Syndication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002866/paging-of-rss-using-system-servicemodel-syndication/23015077#23015077)

My database right now has two tables, one connected to the separate RSS-feeds, and another table to it's content. (Look at it as a TV-series and it's episodes).

Since I want to work with the data from the RSS-feeds further, I need to save it all to my database. But also, keep updating it as the RSS-feed(s) update.

My question is how this is most effectively achieved? And how can i make this an automated process?

Since there will be a lot of RSS-feeds I'm thinking perhaps the most efficient way is to look at the separate RSS-feed and take the date of the last update (stored in my database) and compare it to the RSS-feed. Thus adding the new content and after that updating the "last update" to that of the RSS-feeds latest post?

Comment: Please advise me about if there is anymore info I can add to perhaps get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what i did was i added all my RSS-feeds and their information into one table. Then set up another table for all the feeds content.

After this I built a script that runs every 6 hours, looping through each RSS-feed and then it's contet, checking if new unique posts has been added to the RSS, then these are added to the "content table" as well.

I think I over-complicated the problem, the solution was quite easy. :)